# How to design an algorithm for this? And how to analyse the correctness and the run-time of that algorithm

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, data-structures, time-complexity

Suppose you are given a collection of k 2-dimensional vectors and you are playing a 2-player
the game, where players A and B alternate to choose one vector at a time until all the k vectors have been
partitioned among the two players. Now assume you are player A and your objective is to maximize his/her
resultant vector sum. How to analyze the correctness and the run-time of this algorithm.?

Comment: What is the vector sum? Just the sum of the elements, or Euclidean distance?

Comment: Are both players trying to maximize the same objective function?

Comment: @Carlos You can assume that maximizing the vector sum means maximizing the length of the resulting vector and the vector length is measured in terms of Eucledian length (typical 2-d vectors in Eucledian geometry)

Comment: @EloyPérezTorres Whatever A does, it doesn't effect B.

Comment: I am asking because A decisions affect B because he/she can't take vectors taken by A as they alternate their turns.The strategy of player B is extremely important because of that. Question: Are you assuming then that A can choose any k/2 set with the complacency of player B?

Comment: @EloyPérezTorres We can proceed with assuming it. I can't think otherwise. let me know if u can.

Comment: So to put it another way, you have a pile of vectors and the game is to pick vectors to get as far away from the origin as possible?

Comment: @Carlos Maybe, we can!!